# unordered_map in a function argument

Tags: r, rcpp

#### Question

Why does using `std::unordered_map` as a function argument fail to compile (and how do I solve it)?

#### Example

This first function has the `std::unordered_map` as a function parameter, but fails to compile

```
library(Rcpp)

cppFunction(
  code = 'void test( std::unordered_map< std::string, std::string > um ) {

  }'
  , plugins = "cpp11"
  )
```

Whereas it's fine when declared in the body of the function

```
cppFunction(
  code = 'void test(  ) {
    std::unordered_map< std::string, std::string > um;
  }'
  , plugins = "cpp11"
)
```

---

#### Extra

I've used it successfully as a function argument [here in an inline](https://github.com/SymbolixAU/spatialwidget/blob/master/inst/include/spatialwidget/parameters/parameters.hpp#L63) function in my `spatialwidget` library

---

### Understanding the answer

Thanks to Ralf Stubner for the explanation. In summary, when making an Rcpp function callable by R, there has to be an equivalent R representation of the objects.

This code fails because there is no equivalent `unordered_map` in R

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
void test( std::unordered_map< std::string, std::string > um ) {

}
```

This passes because it's not being called / exported to `R`

```
void test( std::unordered_map< std::string, std::string > um ) {

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use things like `std::vector` and `std::list` as function parameter and return values in functions that are *callable from R* because there exist appropriate specializations for `Rcpp::as` and `Rcpp::wrap` that convert between these C++ data structures and `SEXP`s that R knows about (both directions). Now R has no native map-like data type (although one can use named lists to some extend), which is (probably) why Rcpp has no inbuilt translation for `std::unordered_map`. There is no such limitation for functions that are only callable from C++, which is why your "extra" example works.

In principle you can define such conversion functions yourself, c.f. http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/custom-templated-wrap-and-as-for-seamingless-interfaces/ and references therein. However, you first would have to decide on what type of data structure you want to use at the R-side.

Comment: Very well put in relatively few words.  Besides the Gallery post there is also an entire vignette on this.